# lower case calligraphy for latex

Tags: fonts, formatting, calligraphy

It is said that latex owns an extensive set of symbols. But why no lower case calligraphy package has been developed so far? Due to copyright? I saw they are mature in commercial packages.

Comment: See http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html.  Additionally, if you are using xelatex or lualatex, you can use any of your system fonts, including those which are calligraphic.

Comment: traditionally, lowercase script/calligraphic letters have not been used for math variables.  when type was still metal, one important reason was probably because most script fonts were sloped too heavily to the right (still a problem with many digital fonts).  and it would (at least when i was in school) have been presumptuous for a budding mathematician to propose new notation of that sort.